# How to change image size in plotly dash

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, dashboard, plotly-dash

How do i change the image size? I’ve used the below line of code to insert my image but i cannot seem to figure out how you make it smaller

```
html.Div(html.Img(src=app.get_asset_url('logo.png')))
```

i’ve tried:

```
html.Div(html.Img(src=app.get_asset_url('logo.png')),style={'height':'10%'})
```

any suggestions

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Move your `style` attribute inside `Img`:

```
html.Div(html.Img(src=app.get_asset_url('logo.png'), style={'height':'10%', 'width':'10%'}))
```

Probably `width` is redundant but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try mentioning the *style* inside the html.Img() call, given as follows:

```
html.Img(src=app.get_asset_url('logo.png'),style={'height':'100%','width':'100%'})
```

if you want to fit the image exactly to the page, use 100%. Else reduce the % of height and width accordingly